# How to rewrite this Google Spreadsheet =filter function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is a Google spreadsheet function that prints the common values in columns a,b and c. I'm trying to use it in Excel, but Excel doesn't have the `=filter` function

```
=filter(A:A,countif(B:B,A:A)>0,countif(C:C,A:A)>0,A:A<>"")
```

How would you write this in Excel?

Comment: `SUMIF` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @SUMIF will count them, will it not? the spreadsheet formula prints the common values